# Prove that this function is (or not) surjective

Tags: functions

$f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
$f(a,b) = ab(a+b)/2$

I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: If it is, then given any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, you can provide an $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b)=n$. If not, then you can provide an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a,b)\neq n$ for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. I'd start by trying to see if it isn't- just try out a few natural numbers and see if you can find a preimage for each of them.

Comment: I know that you cannot get 4, but can I just say that $f(1,1), f(1,2), f(2,1)$ do not give 4 and that any value with $a,b \geq 2$ will give a value greater than 4 because it is a multiplication and an addition?

Comment: Actually, you can quite quickly rule out that the function is not surjective. Really fast. What could be the way? Expanding a little on Kevin's hintint: Think about what numbers you just can't produce from $f$, no matter what. There are many such numbers!

Comment: Primes because it is a multiplication of 3 numbers (or 4 if you count the division)? Edit:   :D

Comment: Excellent! :D That is what I thought. (Just note that it is a product of three numbers, divided by 2.)

Comment: But how can I know that the top part will never give me a number that is a prime times 2 (so the bottom will give a prime) like 14 or 223*2?

Comment: That needed some thinking. We only need one counterexample to rule out a function being surjective, and we have atleast one, that is $13$. Try to prove that it can never be returned by the function! Start simple. Then extend that to other primes. Need another hint?

Comment: Well you can try using all the possible combinations until you reach a number higher than 13, because the function is composed of addition, substraction and division and the input is natural numbers, the greater the input the greater the result, but how do you relate this to primes?

Comment: There is a simpler way. Okay, a hint: factorize $2*13$. Now observe why you can't express $26$ as a product of *three* natural numbers. (Find all factors, not just prime factorize). Do you get it now?

Comment: Okay, I have to leave now, so I'll just post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function is not surjective. It can never attain the value of a prime number. Let us consider a prime number $p$. Suppose, $f(a,b)=p$. This implies that $ab(a+b)=2p$.

The factors of $2p$ are $(1, 2, p, 2p)$. From the above equation, we need *three* natural numbers, whose product is $2p$. There are only two ways to do so: $2p=1\times1\times2p$ and $2p=1\times2\times p$. Neither form can be expressed in the form of $a\cdot b\cdot(a+b)$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence the function is not surjective.

Comment: Wow, how do I come with something like that in an exam D:

Thank you!

Comment: When you practice questions, if you are stuck, remember there is an approach you haven't tried yet. Get out of the rut! Also (at home, not in exam), after you have solved a problem, spend some time trying to find a shorter and more elegant approach. This will help develop your creativity! All the best! :)

Comment: Will do! Thank you so much! (I know it says to preferably not write comments just for saying thank you but this was really really helpful)